# WebRTC ICE candidate not generated

Tags: html, webrtc, gstreamer

I'm trying to establish a WebRTC connection between two devices in the same local network. No need to use STUN/TURN servers, because the devices will never be in a different network. The transmission is unidirectional, so it is very simple. Peer1 (I'll call it server) sends a video streams to Peer2 (client) that takes the video stream and plays it in a HTML5 video tag. Peer1 is an application (GStreamer is used to generate the WebRTC stream) and Peer2 is an HTML page.

So:

- Peer1 makes an offer, set it as local description and send it to Peer2
- Peer2 gets the offer and set it as remote description
- Peer2 makes an answer, set it as local description and send it to Peer1
- Peer1 gets the answer and set it as remote description

ICE candidates are exchanged inside the SDP offer/answer.

Both Peers seem to talk to each other correctly and everything works without problems when Peer1 is a Ubuntu PC and Peer2 is a Windows/Ubuntu/Android/etc. device.

However, when Peer1 is an **embedded Linux device**, no stream is transmitted. I think because no connection could be established between the two Peers.

Following are the SDP offer and answer:

**Offer**

{ "type": "offer", "sdp": "v=0\r\no=- 8810393080556377524 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=group:BUNDLE video0\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ice-ufrag:BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf\r\na=ice-pwd:d59671C183yBCXVMyGI8rYpbr2++1gVO\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=framerate:30\r\na=ssrc:3719278214 msid:user2487040517@host-7f0ea73e webrtctransceiver0\r\na=ssrc:3719278214 cname:user2487040517@host-7f0ea73e\r\na=mid:video0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 43:F2:69:6A:64:B9:C7:5B:01:E0:53:2B:1F:5D:E5:D6:F8:E2:48:60:85:F5:5D:3C:7B:EA:A1:8A:27:D0:2D:F3\r\na=candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 50030 typ host\r\na=candidate:2 1 TCP 1015022847 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:3 1 TCP 1010828543 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 56449 typ host tcptype passive\r\na=candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266430 192.168.0.211 42182 typ host\r\na=candidate:5 1 TCP 1015022079 192.168.0.211 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:6 1 TCP 1010827775 192.168.0.211 48465 typ host tcptype passive\r\na=candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 37234 typ host\r\na=candidate:2 2 TCP 1015022846 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:3 2 TCP 1010828542 fe80::823f:5dff:fe08:a48a 35779 typ host tcptype passive\r\na=candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266429 192.168.0.211 36838 typ host\r\na=candidate:5 2 TCP 1015022078 192.168.0.211 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:6 2 TCP 1010827774 192.168.0.211 53511 typ host tcptype passive\r\na=candidate:7 1 UDP 1677722111 88.57.234.178 42182 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 42182\r\na=candidate:8 1 TCP 847249919 88.57.234.178 9 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 9 tcptype active\r\na=candidate:9 1 TCP 843055615 88.57.234.178 48465 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 48465 tcptype passive\r\na=candidate:7 2 UDP 1677722110 88.57.234.178 36838 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 36838\r\na=candidate:8 2 TCP 847249918 88.57.234.178 9 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 9 tcptype active\r\na=candidate:9 2 TCP 843055614 88.57.234.178 53511 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.211 rport 53511 tcptype passive\r\n" }

**Answer**

{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 6620315284746621299 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE video0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n**a=candidate:4266862210 1 udp 2113937151 3370531c-b6c8-4857-9f0b-8b921a6c2e82.local 34246 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999\r\n**a=ice-ufrag:4I1e\r\na=ice-pwd:GveP405bMqPTltX6MTtSmiHj\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E2:6F:85:A2:63:1D:54:0B:1E:57:92:C7:91:7A:03:EE:15:5A:FD:2D:02:94:05:EE:10:74:88:AC:3E:7F:0E:F6\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:video0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\n"}

What puzzles me is that Peer2 generates only one ICE candidate in his answer and it seems "unhealthy" because of the network-cost=999. There should be more than one candidate.

This could be a connection problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I tried also to give STUN servers to both Peers, but it was useless.

Why the answer is so small with only one candidate? Any ideas?

On **Wireshark** I see the following messages:

21  3.328928743 192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

25  5.828279324 192.168.0.229   192.168.0.211   STUN    166 Binding Request user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

26  5.829251123 192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

36  8.328452708 192.168.0.229   192.168.0.211   STUN    166 Binding Request user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

37  8.329379978 192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

46  10.828598399    192.168.0.229   192.168.0.211   STUN    166 Binding Request user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

47  10.829583224    192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

52  13.328730597    192.168.0.229   192.168.0.211   STUN    166 Binding Request user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

53  13.329590515    192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

64  15.829076460    192.168.0.229   192.168.0.211   STUN    166 Binding Request user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e

65  15.830013407    192.168.0.211   192.168.0.229   STUN    150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 192.168.0.229:34246 user: BO1Vk2BiNWvtuAJZOrZnxE/FgpsNtXbf:4I1e